# Alias for a C function in IAR

Tags: c, function, alias, iar

I need a symbol `alias` to be the alias for the function `function` as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649979/gcc-alias-to-function-outside-of-translation-unit-aka-is-this-even-the-right-t), but for IAR compiler/linker. I have tried answers for GCC, but those don't work, obviously:

```
// source code
void alias(void) __attribute__ ((alias ("function")));
Error[Pe130]: expected a "{" C:\project\test.c 61

void alias(void) asm("function");
Error[Pe065]: expected a ";" C:\project\test.c 61

#pragma weak alias=function
Error[e46]: Undefined external "alias" referred in ?ABS_ENTRY_MOD (  ) 

// linker options:
-Dalias=function
Fatal Error[e163]: The command line symbol "function" in -Dalias=function is not defined.
```

Does anyone know how I can define a function alias in IAR/Xlink?

A little background: I'm responsible for a module which is used in several projects. In order to test it, I have developed test cases for testIDEA tool which validate assertions at certain breakpoints. However, some common functions have different names in different projects (e.g. the initialization function could be called `init()`, `init_mcu()`, `startup()` etc.) so every time my module is integrated in a new project, I have to modify my test cases to match the new function names. What I'd like to do instead is to define a common alias (e.g. `test_init()`) to whatever the init function is called, so that my test cases can always set a breakpoint using this common name. I expect this symbol to make it to the ELF file, where it can be seen by the debugger.

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25620087/2703418

Comment: Has IAR moved their support to stack overflow? The tools are pretty expensive, so I'd expect there is some kind of support and documentation. What does the documentation say? What did you not understand?

Comment: How about #define the functions? For example, for module foo there will be a `test_foo.h` and a #define INIT init;#define DO_STUFF do_specific_foo_stuff

Comment: @bzeaman Nice find, but it doesn't seem to work. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Olaf The only alias I've found in the documentation is `#pragma include_alias`, and that's not what I want. PS: If you don't like IAR questions, why don't you just ignore the tag?

Comment: @IshayPeled `#define` symbols only exist at compile time, they don't go to the ELF file. I can't see them in the debugger.

Comment: Don't put words in my mouth! In case you cannot read between the lines: I just wrote they have a support, so why not ask them in the first place?

Comment: @Olaf, I'll write to the support then. Still, I don't understand what's wrong with asking here.

Comment: Site rules! You did apparently show no effort (no, trying/failing gcc's way is not) to solve yourself.

Comment: `Undefined external "alias" referred in ?ABS_ENTRY_MOD` Did you define `alias` before that line?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'm guessing you want the function name in the elf section because you use some sort of generalized code to access it, if I'm right, you can still use a header - the lookup will be done by the compiler using the #define instead of during runtime

Comment: @IshayPeled: Preprocessor macros are not alias symbols. They serve a completely different purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a close look at [`xlink` options](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/005316/xlink.ENU.pdf) I've found the one which sort of suits my needs:

> -e -enew=old [,old] …
>
> Use -e to configure a program at link time by redirecting a function call from one function to another.
>
> This can also be used for creating stub functions; i.e. when a system is not yet complete, undefined function calls can be directed to a dummy routine until the real function has been written.

I ended up with this code:

```
void alias(void) {
// copy the body of function()
}

// Linker parameters
-ealias=function
```

This redirects all calls to `function()` to `alias()`, regardless the actual name `function` has. Sure it's an ugly hack because I have to copy the code, but I get what I wanted: I can set a breakpoint to `alias()` by name.

Comment: Good alternative solution! I guess you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [IAR C/C++ Development Guide](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf) (p. 258):

> To make the definition of `foo` a *weak* definition, write:
>   `#pragma weak foo`
>   To make `NMI_Handler` a weak alias for `Default_Handler`, write:
>   `#pragma weak NMI_Handler=Default_Handler`
>   If `NMI_Handler` is not defined elsewhere in the program, all references to `NMI_Handler` will refer to `Default_Handler`.

So, try something like this:

```
void f1(void);
void f2(void);

#pragma weak f1=f2

void f2(void) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm upvoting your answer since it's clever and may help others, but it didn't help me. When I do `#pragma weak f1=f2`, `f1` simply doesn't appear in the ELF file. If I try to force it with `-gf1` linker option, I get the `Error [e46]: Undefined external "f1" referred in ?ABS_ENTRY_MOD (  )`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Just a guess: Maybe you need to do `#pragma required=f1` after the `weak` pragma.